# How to decide which image to show based on a date value on a webpage using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, date

I have a table in which I display a date value on each row on Literal fields, the row also has a space for an icon, it has to either display a red icon if the date is outdated, or a green icon if the date is ok, the date value I'm displaying comes from a database, what I want to do is to show either icon based on the comparison with the date on the table and today's date. So if the date on the table is 10/14/2012 and today is the same day, the icon will be green, if the date on the table is 10/10/2012 or any other date prior today's date, it has to display the red icon.
I know almost nothing about JavaScript but I think it's what I need for this, both images are already stored on the server, and I'm developing on asp on VB.NET.

Comment: you could use js, but if you're generating the page with these icons on the server, then do your green/red decisions at the time the page is generated.

Answer (score 1):

i have used jquery for this to work for what you asked see the link for the code snippet

http://jsfiddle.net/GbGVD/3/